# Setting sentinel value and stopping loop with sentinel value

Tags: python, loops, sentinel, accumulator

I have figured out the totals and they are running as supposed to. I just can't get the program to stop once I input done. It just keeps looping. I have set the sentinel equal to "done". Can someone please help?

```
# SuperMarket.py - This program creates a report that lists weekly hours worked 
# by employees of a supermarket. The report lists total hours for 
# each day of one week. 
# Input:  Interactive
# Output: Report. 
# Declare variables.
HEAD1 = "WEEKLY HOURS WORKED"
DAY_FOOTER = "Day Total "
SENTINEL = "done"   # Named constant for sentinel value
hoursWorked = 0     # Current record hours
hoursTotal = 0      # Hours total for a day
prevDay = ""        # Previous day of week
notDone = True      # loop control
# Print two blank lines.
print("\n\n")
# Print heading.
print("\t" + HEAD1)
# Print two blank lines.
print("\n\n")

# Read first record 
dayOfWeek = input("Enter day of week or done to quit: ")
if dayOfWeek  == SENTINEL:
    notDone = False
else:
    prevDay = dayOfWeek
    hoursWorked = input("Enter hours worked:")
    while notDone == True:
        dayOfWeek = input("Enter day of week or done to quit: ")
        hoursTotal = hoursTotal + int(hoursWorked)
        if prevDay != dayOfWeek:
            print("\t" + DAY_FOOTER + str(hoursTotal))
            prevDay = dayOfWeek #Include work done in the dayChange()function
            hoursTotal = 0
        hoursWorked = input("Enter hours worked:")
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out everything. I had to add another if statement to get the loop to break within the while statement!

```
# SuperMarket.py - This program creates a report that lists weekly hours worked 
# by employees of a supermarket. The report lists total hours for 
# each day of one week. 
# Input:  Interactive
# Output: Report. 
# Declare variables.
HEAD1 = "WEEKLY HOURS WORKED"
DAY_FOOTER = "Day Total "
SENTINEL = "done"   # Named constant for sentinel value
hoursWorked = 0     # Current record hours
hoursTotal = 0      # Hours total for a day
prevDay = ""        # Previous day of week
notDone = True      # loop control
# Print two blank lines.
print("\n\n")
# Print heading.
print("\t" + HEAD1)
# Print two blank lines.
print("\n\n")

# Read first record 
dayOfWeek = input("Enter day of week or done to quit: ")
if dayOfWeek  == SENTINEL:
    notDone = False
else:
    prevDay = dayOfWeek
    hoursWorked = input("Enter hours worked:")



    while notDone == True:
        dayOfWeek = input("Enter day of week or done to quit: ")
        hoursTotal = hoursTotal + int(hoursWorked)
        if prevDay != dayOfWeek:
            print("\t" + DAY_FOOTER + str(hoursTotal))
            if dayOfWeek == "done":
                break
            else:
                prevDay = dayOfWeek #Include work done in the dayChange()function
                hoursTotal = 0
        hoursWorked = input("Enter hours worked:")
```